# In Wyndham's "Confidence Trick", a sign at an Underground station in Hell is misread as "Something Avenue". What should it be?

Tags: pronunciation, john-wyndham

John Wyndham wrote a short story, "Confidence Trick", about a London Underground train which takes its passengers to Hell. The story was included in his book *Jizzle*. In the story, after an unusually long Underground journey from central London, this happens to the train:

> The light grew brighter still, the speed dwindled, and presently they
> were running into a station. They leaned forward to catch the name,
> but could see no plate on the wall. Mrs Branton, on the other side,
> suddenly craned across.
>
> There!’ she said. They turned quickly, but not soon enough.
>
> ‘It was something Avenue, or Avenue something,’ she said.
>
> ‘Well, we’ll soon find out now,’ Mr Forkett reassured them.

The passengers then see a red demon carrying a trident and net. It makes everyone get off the train, and they end up on the platform. The protagonist, Henry, then sees a station sign:

> Henry glanced about. The dim rosy light was strong enough for him to
> see and read the station’s nameplate.
>
> ‘Something Avenue!’ he repeated under his breath. Tch-tch!’
>
> Mrs Branton overheard him, and looked at it.
>
> ‘Well, if that doesn’t spell “Avenues”, what does it spell?’ she
> demanded.

Can anyone think what it *does* spell? My guess is that it's something to do with Heaven, but I can't think what, and the train is in Hell anyway. I've never been able to work this out, and I first read the story as a teenager.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

One assumes that it said [Avernus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Avernus#:%7E:text=The%20entrance%20to%20Hell%20or,A%20lake%20in%20Southern%20Italy.), which is Latin for "Hell"

Comment: Wyndham, presumably studied Latin at Bedales. He uses it with moderate regularity in his books and short fiction; http://bedalesschools.daisy.websds.net/Filename.ashx?systemFileName=BEDAR1917-1918_Iss_030.pdf&origFilename=BEDAR1917-1918_Iss_030.pdf

Comment: In the times Wyndham was writing most well-educated Englishmen would have known some Latin.

Comment: Yes. And, for the same reason, a fair amount of poetry, and been able to compose their own. I think the verse at the top of http://gritinthegears.blogspot.com/2010/03/oh-im-burning-my-brains-in-backroom.html was written by Wyndham, for The Kraken Wakes.